# Identifier is not a camel case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, eslint, react-intl

I have to import from a module and I have an error Identifier 'locale_en' is not in camel case. How can I do to resolve this.

```
import locale_en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en'
```

I use the module 'react-intl' and I try to add this : `camelcase: ["error", {properties: "never"}]` in my rules and it's still not working

Edit : I find the solution : the rules is : `"camelcase": [1, {"properties": "never"}]`

Comment: `camelcase` is not a camel case but `camelCase` is.

Comment: Definition for rule 'camelCase' was not found ...

Comment: Ironic that [the `camelcase` rule's name](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase#rule-details) is not in camel case.

Comment: Have you tried aliasing?

Comment: What are you talking about aliasing ? @user10340130

Comment: I mean `import locale_en as local from 'react-intl/locale-data/en'`. Though I am not sure that it will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can now flexibly `allow` certain identifiers (regexp also) to be non-camelcase:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "camelcase": ["error", {"allow": ["aa_bb"]}]
    }
}
```

See: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase#allow